# Saving User Input in a JBoss Seam Web Project web page

Tags: jsf, jboss, seam

I have a question for any JBoss Seam developers out there:

I am creating a web project using JBoss Seam by generating entities and reverse-engineering code from existing database tables.  This is my first time developing a web app in JBoss/Java/JSF, being an old school .NET web developer from years ago.

How do I save user input in text controls, so that it stays on the web page after a page refresh?  I used to use Viewstate or Sessionstate in .NET, not sure what the equivalent of this would be in Java/JSF.  Someone mentioned using java beans, but not sure how to do that, and Googling produces little help.

Any comments much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than going through the steps required here, it might be easier for you to go through the Seam tutorial, which will give you the basics. You can then clarify things here afterwards:

http://docs.jboss.org/seam/latest/reference/en-US/html/tutorial.html#registration-example